# Merge data.frames cause error

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets. Both have the same IDs, same rows with different results

```
data<-read.table(file="file.profile", header=T)
data$PHENO<-data$PHENO-1
data$ID<-paste(data$FID,":",data$IID, sep="")

> head(data)
      FID    IID PHENO CNT  CNT2 SCORE ID
    1 FID1   10     0 10000 100 0.01 FID1:10
    2 FID2   10     0 10000 100 0.01 FID2:10

> cov<-read.table(file="cov.txt", header=T)
> cov$ID<-paste(cov$FID,":",cov$IID, sep="")

> head(cov)
  FID IID COV1 COV2    COV3    COV4    COV5 COV6 COV7 PHENO ID
1 FID1  10    0    0 0.101  0.10  0.22    2   179     222 FID1:10
2 FID2  10    0    0 0.102  0.10  0.23    2   176     222 FID2:10

> data<-merge(cov,data,by.x="ID", by.y="ID", all=T)

> head(data)
         ID   FID.x IID.x COV1 COV2    COV3    COV4    COV5 COV6 COV7 PHENO.x
1 FID1:10 FID1  10    0    0 0.101  0.10  0.22    2   179     222
2 FID2:10 FID2   10   0    0 0.102  0.10  0.23    2   176     222
    FID.y IID.y PHENO.y    CNT  CNT2     SCORE
    FID1   10     0 10000 100 0.01 
    FID2   10     0 10000 100 0.01
```

Why do I have ".x" and ".y" added to my columns ? How can I avoid this ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of your data frames have identically-named columns, `merge()` will append an `x` or `y` to the column names to identify from which dataset they came.

Here, you have a column named `FID` and `IID` in both `data` and `cov`; as a result, `FID.x` and `IID.x` are from the `cov` data frame and `FID.y` and `IID.y` are from the `data` data frame.

You avoid this by having unique column names across both datasets.

Comment: But I am trying to merge it using one particular column as a reference, doesn;t that help ? Do you have a suggestion how can i avoid the prefix .x/.y to column names?

Comment: @Guest You could use `unique`, `setdiff` etc to subset the columns and then `merge`

Comment: ah okay, thank you Steven and akrun, it worked with uniq column names.